# how do variables work in Javascript? Can variable Value change during setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
function Notification(type) 
{
    switch (type) 
    {
        case "success":
           notificationID="not1";
           break;
        case "error":
           notificationID="not2";
           break;  
    }

    setNotificationTimeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
        jQuery('#' + notificationID).fadeOut(200, function () {
            var notification = document.getElementById(notificationID);
            if (notification) 
            {
                jQuery(notification.parentNode).remove();

                if (type == "success")
                        DoSomething();
            }

            setNotificationTimeoutId = null;
        });
    }, 5000);
}
```

My question is, if the function(Notification) gets called on a click event, and if it gets called two times(first with Notification("success") then with Notification("error")) by two click events, is it possible that the second function call changes the type variables value for the first function call?

For example: when the first call(one with success) enters the function inside the setTimeout(a second call to Notification already been made with type = "error") it sees the variable 'type' as "error" even though this call was the first and it wass called with type = "success"?

Comment: no, it is not possible, there should be another trick

Comment: Yes it is possible, in fact that is what is already happening in your code. To change that, add `var notificationID;` at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if the function `Notification` gets called on a click event, and if it gets called two times (first with `Notification("success")` then with `Notification("error")`) by two click events, is it possible that the second function call changes the `type` variables value for the first function call?

No. The `type` variable is a parameter and therefore scope-bound to your function. It's value won't change in subsequent calls, every function call creates a new instance of this variable and has no access to others.

Your anonymous function for the timeout has a scope which is a "subscope" of `Notification`'s one, so it will always access the right `type` variable.

But your `notificationID` is a global variable (not local-scoped), and the same variable instance will be used by all calls to `Notification` and from all timeouts. So it will happen that the second call to `Notification` changes it before the timeout from the first accesses it. To fix this, add the `var` keyword.

Or, as `setNotificationTimeoutId` is also in an outer scope and can be accessed from both calls, you could (should?) clear any active timeouts before creating the new one, by adding the following line:

```
clearTimeout(setNotificationTimeoutId);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this was the type of answer i was looking for. In my  true code, notificationId is local too :)

Comment: I do not want to clear any active timeouts, as I want multiple setTimeouts to run at the same time

Answer (score 1):

You should localize your notificationID variable, as it is global, allowing the second time the function runs to change the output of the first time it runs.

use var to localize:

```
 var notificationID;

 switch (type) 
 {
    case "success":
      notificationID="not1";
      break;
    case "error":
      notificationID="not2";
      break;
 }
```

Comment: my interest is in variable type, as I have mentioned. notificationId is global here, however in my code it is local, I just didnt want to copy paste the whole code. Sry if I pushed you to misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/vgSGL/

Instead of using setTimeout, you can use jQuery's delay method, which is similar.

Hope it helps?

Gav